# Django template remove sub list

Tags: python, django

Maybe a stupid question but how do I remove a sublist from list in django template 
I have something like this:

```
{% for j in sub_com|slice:"1" %}

 {% for k in  j|slice:"3" %}

       <li> {{k}} </li>

   {%  endfor %}

   {# remove sublist from list here #}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use [`templateContext.pop`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context.pop) here.

```
{% for j in sub_com|slice:"1" %}
   {% for k in  j|slice:"3" %}
       <li> {{k}} </li>
   {%  endfor %}
   {{ j.pop.0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants : `{{ sub_com.pop.0 }}`, anyway neither your code or my suggestion worked for me. I am getting `TemplateSyntaxError` for both.

Comment: It should have been `{{ j.pop.0 }}` instead or `{% j.pop.0 %}`

Comment: Yeah, +1 for answer but this should be done in the backend instead of his template IMO :)

Comment: @limelights I had that as a comment. Dont know when i deleted it (accidentally)

Comment: Ah, sorry for that then! :)